# Problema con created_at / updated_at al actualizar registro en laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Estoy programando el CRUD de la user (modificada) en mi proyecto laravel (5.6) pero al actualizar un usuario me da conflictos con las fechas de registro/actualización, o al menos eso es lo que he alcanzado a entender luego de revisar varias consultas en la web.

```
Mi  update: 
 /**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $usuario = User::find($request['id']);
    $usuario->id_role = $request['id_role'];
    $usuario->name = $request['nom_usuario'];
    $usuario->last_name = $request['ape_usuario'];
    $usuario->rut_user = $request['rut_usuario'];
    $usuario->telefono1 = $request['telefono1'];
    $usuario->telefono2 = $request['telefono2'];
    $usuario->email = $request['ema_usuario'];
    $usuario->save();
    return Redirect::to('/usuarios')->with('notice', 'El usuario ha sido modificado correctamente.');
}
```

Mi modelo:

```
<?php

 namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function getListado(){

    $usuarios = $this->join('roles', 'users.id_role', '=', 'roles.id_role')
                ->select('users.*', 'roles.des_role')
                ->orderBy('name', 'ASC');
    return $usuarios;

}
}
```

Al añadir en el modelo el 
    public $timestamps = false;
Guarda pero no registra la fecha de actualización (que es el cometido de dicha declaración) Sin embargo, eso también necesito guardarlo, obviamente.

Agradezco cualquier aporte.
[image: imagen de error]

He estado recurriendo a éste recurso con mucha frecuencia últimamente, creo que es lo mas sano cuando estamos aprendiendo una nueva herramienta y no hallamos la respuesta indicada.  Agradezco todas las orientaciones.

Comment: Bienvenida Maria, no llego a entender cual es el problema o que es lo queres lograr hacer, podes explicarte mejor.

Comment: Gracias.  Lo que necesito es saber por qué no me actualiza sin colocarle public $timestamps = false;

Comment: y que error te tira?

Comment: InvalidArgumentException
    Data missing

Comment: si puedes, pega todo el mensaje de error completo o adjunta una screen del mismo.

Comment: Agregada. Si, es el formato de las fechas, ya lo he probado, el asunto es que si funciona para crear pero no para editar... No entiendo por qué

Comment: Hay algo raro, como es la migration de la tabla? que tipo de campo usas para los campos created_at y updated_at?

Comment: datetime en  sqlserver... Ya conseguí que funcionará, seteando el campo updated_at = null en el storage()

Comment: Prueba añadir `created_at` y `updated_at` al `$fillable` del modelo.

Comment: Una consulta, cómo creaste el updated_at en tu migración?

Laravel tiene el comando (en la migración) `$table->timestamps();`
Con eso creas el created_at y el updated_at.
Te pregunto porque el error que te tira, si te fijas en el pantallazo que pusiste.  Primero pregunta si $date, es una instancia de DateTime.  Como no lo es, tira el error.
No será que creaste tu campo updated_at solamente como date en lugar de un timestamp o DateTime?

Comment: [![Los campos deben seren parecidos a estos.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFW77.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFW77.jpg) [![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejcqf.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejcqf.jpg) **Verifica los campos en tu base de datos.**

Answer (score 0):

Intenta agregar en el update:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $usuario = User::find($request['id']);
    $usuario->id_role = $request['id_role'];
    $usuario->name = $request['nom_usuario'];
    $usuario->last_name = $request['ape_usuario'];
    $usuario->rut_user = $request['rut_usuario'];
    $usuario->telefono1 = $request['telefono1'];
    $usuario->telefono2 = $request['telefono2'];
    $usuario->email = $request['ema_usuario'];
    $usuario->updated_at = Carbon\Carbon::now(); //Agregas la fecha de actualización
    $usuario->save();
    return Redirect::to('/usuarios')->with('notice', 'El usuario ha sido modificado correctamente.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No tendrías por qué estar actualizando manualmente tu updated_at o created_at.

**Si haces una modificación y el modelo no cambia, el updated_at no se actualizará**, pero podrías perfectamente, **si por X motivo quieres forzar ese cambio**, hacer esto:

```
$tuModelo->touch();
```

**Con eso se actualiza el updated_at.**

Ahora bien, otra cosa que **me preocupa** en lo que veo, es que muestras el **fillable** de User y tienes esto:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];
```

Eso significa, que si utilizas el ->save();  **cualquier otra propiedad de tu modelo no se actualizará porque no está en el fillable.**  Y eso podría estar causando que **no se actualice realmente tu modelo** (en caso de que ni **name**, ni **email** ni **password** hayan cambiado) y que por eso no cambie el updated_at.

**Te aconsejo agregar las otras propiedades del modelo (o columnas de la tabla) que se permitirán modificar, al $fillable.**  Te quedaría algo así:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'email',
    'password',
    'id_role',
    'last_name',
    'rut_user',
    'telefono1',
    'telefono2'
];
```

O algo por el estilo según tus campos reales que desconozco.

Lo otro que me queda es preguntarte (pero dudo que sea el problema) es cómo creaste updated_at en tu migración.  ¿La creaste así?

```
$table->timestamps();
```

Con eso creas el created_at y el updated_at.
Lo importante es que sean dateTimes o timestamps para que no tengas problemas.

Comment: Si, en principio se creó tal cual viene por defecto en laravel  
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Comment: Entonces revisa lo que te comento del $fillable, debe ser tu problema, sino no tendrías por qué hacerlo manualmente, no es la idea.  Si tu modelo no cambia al actualizar, el updated_at no cambiará, comprueba que el modelo esté realmente cambiando o puedes realizar el touch() para ver si te funciona.  Si touch() te diera un error, eso sería porque tienes algo muy mal jaja.
Por supuesto que para que todo esto funcione bien, no añadas el $timestamps = false;

Comment: Gracias, haré lo que me indicas.

Comment: Gracias, hice lo que me indicas y no funciona, ya lo dejaré con el updated_at = null... Es la única manera en que me ha funcionado.  Gracias a todos por las sugerencias.

Comment: Ejecutaste el touch()? Qué sucede si lo usas? se cae? Si es así está malo el tipo de dato de tu updated_at probablemente.

Comment: Agregué a mi modelo User protected $touches = ['post'];  como leí en la documentación, asumo que es lo mismo que me sugieres, pero igual sigue dando problemas con "Data missing" hasta para el "recuperar contraseña" Ya no se que hacer...

Comment: Si, claramente algo debes tener muy mal ahí por ahí.
Ese error de Data missing, si te sigue saliendo, asumo que es porque sigues intentando "forzar" el updated_at y al setear la fecha con Carbon el formato que le entregas no es el que espera.
Te sugiero que dejes de forzar el updated_at (no lo guardes manualmente), simplemente intentes guardar tu modelo, siguiendo la sugerencia que te dije del $fillable y si al momento de guardar, te da un error, que por favor nos copies y pegues el texto de error de la forma mas completa posible, o por último un pantallazo.
A ver si llegamos a algo.

Comment: Listo, volví a subir otro pantallazo del error en cuestión

Comment: ¿Sigues intentando agregar manualmente el updated_at?
Porque ese error significa una sola cosa, que estás guardando una fecha con formato datetime (como los timestamps) con un formato incorrecto.
Si estás intentando guardar updated_at a mano **no lo hagas**.
Quítalo de tus parámetros y también borra el public $timestamps = false; 
**Lo que tango claro, es que tu erros es porque estás intentando guardar un datetime probablemente con un formato erroneo como '2017-01-04 00:52', donde faltan los segundos, por eso dice Data Missing, faltan datos.
No guardes el updated_at y prueba el save().

Comment: No, ya lo dejé como me indicas, que se agregue automáticamente y no manualmente.  Creo que  el problema está en que sql server lo define como datetime y no como timestamp aunque el migration esté como timestamp ...

Answer (score 0):

Comparto la solución, tal vez le sirva a alguien mas:::
Efectivamente!!! El problema con sql server es que el tipo de dato "timestamp" como tal no existe, al crear una tabla, bien sea por migrations o sql, sql server lo toma como datetime, para que laravel funcione correctamente, el tipo de dato para todos los campos de fecha debe ser datetime2...

Gracias a todos por sus aportes!!!

Seguimos aprendiendo :)